# get set variable in typescript angular 2

Tags: typescript

I'm using angular 2. I'm not understand set variable. Variable _isLoading was set in "this.observable.filter((event)" but it not change in template
This is code ts:

```
export class SecureComponent implements OnInit {
    public _isLoading: boolean;
    on(eventName, callback) {
    this.observable.filter((event) => {
      this._isLoading = event.isLoading; //set "_isLoading" but It isn't change value in template.
      console.log(this._isLoading);
      return event.name === eventName;
    }).subscribe(callback);
}

ChangeIsLoading(isLoading){
    this._isLoading = !isLoading; // I try to change value in function. it work very well
  }
}
```

This is template:

```html
<div class="app layout-fixed-header">
    <sidebar-panel-left></sidebar-panel-left>
    <header-navbar></header-navbar>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="main-content">
            <spinner *ngIf="_isLoading"></spinner>
            <span (click)='ChangeIsLoading(_isLoading)'>{{_isLoading}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

THis is ApiService(When get data from server then variable change value):

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
 private _secureComponent: SecureComponent = new SecureComponent();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this._secureComponent.on('event1', (event)=>{
        });
    }
setLoaderAnimation(isLoading) {
        this._secureComponent.broadcast({
            name: 'setLoading',
            isLoading: isLoading
        });
    }
public apiGet(url) {
        this.setLoaderAnimation(true);
        return new Promise((response, reject) => {
            let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: this.getHeaders() });
            this.http.get(url, options).toPromise()
                .then((value) => {
                    response(value.json());
                    this.setLoaderAnimation(false);
                }).catch(function (value) {
                    reject(value);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a Value is useful when you want a child component to automatically set a value and refresh. Here you want a component to display a loading or not. First mistake is to declare those var in the service. The service must return a promise or an observable, to ensure the data is returned. So you better change the loading variable location to put it in a component. You can both change it when you http get or once the response is returned.

To make it clearer in your case, create a component to call from the main component (the one who will get the data) and create a var _myVar and an 
`@Input set myVar(data: type) { this._myVar = data }`

Your child component can now have an independent behavior every time your parent will modify its value (isLoading)

```
<app-child [myVar]="isLoading"></app-child>
```

Just call your service from a component that manage the loading ;)

Comment: I try @Input() in SecureComponent and in apiservice.ts <app-secure [myVar]="isLoading"></app-secure> but it not working.
I using @Input in homeComponent.ts when SecureComponent  point url-> working good
P/s: SecureComponent  as ParentComponent

Comment: Can you show a sample of your main component ts , the one that include the secure component + precise what's not working. Edit : ok so in homeComponent here you call your apiService in a function, by injecting it in the constructor. Did you do it or are you trying to call the service from the secure component ?

Comment: I will check it tonight and try to provide you a solution

Comment: So I read your code, and to be honest it's a mess, you have ApiService that contains @Component which is not the way to write service, your plunkr does not work. I think you should write your service from scratch and follow the "Hero Tour". Another thing : don't inject your Api service in the home service unless they depend on each other, and you'll need to configure your app to work this way : https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angular-3b253df5c21 
Edit your post once you'll have a working plunkr or stackblitz